# Why an object is destroyed more than one time? [c++11]

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, scope

In this little example one object is destructed multiple times...

Output can be found at : http://ideone.com/ddJ6Hh

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
struct sA
{
    static int n;
    int id;
    string name;
    sA(string s="default"):id(++n),name(s)  {   cout<<"object '"<<name<<"' created\t  id="<<id<<"\taddr="<<this<<"\tn="<<n<<"\n";   }
    ~sA()   {   cout<<"object '"<<name<<"' destroyed\t  id="<<id<<"\taddr="<<this<<"\tn="<<--n<<"\n";   }

//  sA(const sA& other):id(++n),name(other.name+"_Copy")    {   cout<<"object '"<<name<<"' copied\t  id="<<id<<"\taddr="<<this<<"\tn="<<n<<"\n";    }
    sA operator=(const sA& other)   =delete;
};
int sA::n;




int main()
{
    function<void(void)> vp;

    {
        sA f("1___This Object will die when others need it...");
        sA b("2___This Object will not die ...");
        vp=[&f,b]
        {
            cout<<"Hello\n";
            cout<<b.name<<"||\t addr="<<&b<<"\t|<*>| Stack Data is ok\n";
            cout<<f.name<<"||\t addr="<<&f<<"\t|<*>| Stack Data may not be there\n";
        };
        vp();
        cout<<"********* Block end\n";
    }

    sA k("3__test obj");
    vp();
    return 0;
}
```

Till now the possible reasons which I hv figured out are :

1) reference of local object taken by lambda which goes out of scope alive.[for object 'f']

2) default copy constructor called and the older copy gets destroyed [for object b]

But these reasons are not answering the following facts:

1) Even before end of the inner most block two objects destroyed. [ Block end is identified]

2) Maximum of 1 extra destruction must be there but it reveals 3. [as n=-3 at the end of program]

3) If I enable copy constructor recursively copies are being created but at the end 'total no of construction=total no of destruction'. [ as n=0 at the end of the program]

Is this the behavior  of lambda(without mutable) ?

Or Its just another bug in code?

Also what is the lifetime of lambda and its captured variables?

Comment: This segfaults (elsewhere) because you capture by reference `f` in the lambda `vp=[&f,b]` and then attempt to call it again with `vp()` after the outer block scope because the reference is no longer valid. You invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your object is not destroyed 2 times a copy of it is destroyed since in the clusore `b` is captured  by value

Comment: If you increment `n` in the move and copy constructors (which the automatically generated ones don't do) `n` will get to 0 at the end.

Comment: Hint: Add `cout<<this` to your constructors and destructors.

Comment: cout<<"object '"<<name<<"' created\t  id="<<id<<"\taddr="<<this<<"\tn="<<n<<"\n";
CANT U SEE THIS PART ?
.....dr="<<this<<"\t.....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you fix the undefined behaviour in your code, there are some copies which are not immediately obvious.

```
vp=[&f,b]
{
    //...
};
```

There are actually three copies of `b` in that statement.

1. Copy into lambda
2. Copy into parameter of `std::function` constructor
3. Copy into internal storage of `std::function`

Those first two copies will be destroyed by the end of the statement, so you see two destructions. It's not the same object which is being destroyed twice.

`std::function` has to do type erasure, so it can actually be quite expensive. You could mitigate this with reasonable move constructors, but generally it's best to use the original lambda type when you can.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda objects captures by reference the local object `f`, which goes out of scope the on the line after your "Block End" print (and thus is destroyed). You thus have a dangling reference in the second call to `vp()`, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `f` isn't destroyed twice, `b` is.

Comment: @TartanLlama - agree that `f` isn't destroyed twice, removed that part. Not sure I agree that `b` is though - not the same `b` anyway

Comment: Yeah, not the same `b`, copies of it.